# Select multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, count, where-clause

I have a string of values like '409.7,409,334.2' ; the number of elements varies.
I like to COUNT how many records there are with 409.7
+ how many records there are with 409
+ how many records there are with 334.2
Something like?

```
SELECT COUNT "PrimaryKey" 
FROM Data 
WHERE "Program Number" IN '409.7,409,334.2' AND "Date" >=  1/1/2020
```

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Couldn't you split it up before creating the SQL?

Comment: Do you need separate counts for each program number, or just the total of all of them?

Comment: I can reformat the string in say.. a list

Comment: ```WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`Program Number`, '409.7,409,334.2')```

Comment: Just a total count

Comment: If you can reformat it as a list, then it should be ```Where `Program Number` IN (409.7, 409, 334.2)```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the overall count, you can use `find_in_set()`  and aggregation:

```
select count(*) cnt
from data
where find_in_set(program_number, '409.7,409,334.2')
```

If you want a per-element count, then one option is conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(find_in_set(program_number, '409.7,409,334.2') = 1) cnt1,
    sum(find_in_set(program_number, '409.7,409,334.2') = 2) cnt2,
    sum(find_in_set(program_number, '409.7,409,334.2') = 3) cnt3
from data
where find_in_set(program_number, '409.7,409,334.2')
```

If you have a lot of elements the the csv list, you might as well generate rows than column. This gives you the count of matches for each element *index*:

```
select find_in_set(program_number, '409.7,409,334.2') element_index, count(*) cnt
from data
group by element_index
```

Comment: I don't think `program_number` is a comma-separated list, just this literal string.

Comment: @Barmar: yes I am assuming that it's a csv string, as showned by OP: `'409.7,409,334.2'`

Comment: I don't know how many elements there will be in the list. Probably around a dozen

Comment: You seem to have it backwards. `Program Number` is a single number, he wants to check if it's in a comma-separated list.

Comment: @Barmar: ah yes, I see your point, thank you. I changed my answer.